# Is there a way to reference a variable from an external document with PHP?

Tags: php, reference, variables, document, external

I wanted to use PHP do do a little thing, but I needed to know how to get a variable from an external document (say external.php) and use it in a function in a PHP document (internal.php). 
I was thinking maybe something like this:

Code for external.php

```
$variable = "true";
```

Code for internal.php

```
if ($GETFROM{'/external.php'}['variable']) 
echo "It worked";
```

Is there any possible way to do something like this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to include a specific value from an include file directly *into* a variable in your current document, you can also include a PHP file which returns the value.

For example:

inc.php

```
<?php
    return "Hello, world!";
?>
```

index.php

```
<?php
    $var = include "inc.php";

    if(isset($var) && !empty($var)) {
        echo "It worked!\n";
        echo "Value: {$var}";
    }
    else {
        echo "It failed!";
    }
?>
```

Comment: Downvoted because this code ist wrong. return statement can only be used in ca function and the include line just makes no sense.

Comment: @Thomas. The code works perfectly. Try it if you have doubts. And please, at least RTFM before deciding somebody is wrong. *(http://php.net/include - Example #5)*

Comment: +1 to offset Thomas' downvote.  @Thomas - The code isn't wrong, you are.

Answer (score 7):

Use the include function for that. In internal.php

```
include 'external.php';
if($variable)
{
    echo "It worked";
}
```

Note: This is great for configuration files or loading of classes or helper functions, but try to avoid too many includes in random places in your sourcecode. This can make your code very hard to read.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the correct answer already given, you could take a look at [PHP classes and objects](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php) so that you can access data from external sources (classes) without the risk of messing up with duplicate variable names which could be overwritten with a simple include.

Answer (score 2):

Do

```
include('external.php');
```

then `$variable` contains the string "true".